# Domain and Range, Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Find the domain and range:**
$f(x,y) = \sqrt(y^2-x)$

**Solution:**
I found the domain to be 
$D = \{(x,y)|y^2 \ge x\}$ and range to be $R = \{z| [0, \infty)\}$

**Question:** I am having difficulty figuring out if this is the correct solution, mostly because my textbook doesn't specify much on range and I always become very forgetful when it comes to graphs.

Comment: Hint. You need the inner expression to be great than zero, since $ln(z)$ has domain in the positive reals.

Comment: Now you mean the square root???

Comment: Just realized I entered the wrong problem.... Solution stands, is it correct?

Comment: yeah sorry entered the wrong one, my bad

Comment: @Stan-Lee Yes your solution is correct.

Comment: @Mattos thank you, wasn't sure whether it was or not, thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{y^2-x}$$
Since the domain of $\sqrt{z}$ is $\{z\in\mathbb R:z\geq 0\}$, then for $f(x,y)$ we have
$$ y^2-x\geq 0 $$
$$ y^2\geq x$$
Therefore the domain of $f(x,y)$ is
$$ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y^2\geq x\} $$
And the range is
$$ \{z\in\mathbb R:z\geq 0\} $$